# Flutter Firestore: specific documents from a collection (Firestore.collection.where)

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, where-clause

I am using Firebase Cloud Firestore, and I want to pick specific documents from a collection. I want to call documents whose `permission` field is 'everyone' or 'groupA'.

```
stream: Firestore.instance
    .collection('Posts')
    .orderBy('date')
    .where('permission', isEqualTo: 'everyone')
    .where('permission', isEqualTo: 'groupA')
    .snapshot(),
```

I tried this but it is trying to bring me the intersection. I also tried:

```
    .where('permission', arrayContains: 'everyone')
    .where('permission', arrayContains: 'groupA')
```

But this gives me errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase does not support logical OR queries. In this case, you should create a separate query for each OR condition and merge the query results in your app.